# Send nested array via Laravel Http Client

Tags: laravel, http, httpclient, guzzle

I want to send request to an API website containing nested params via Laravel Http Client (Laravel 7.x)

```
$params = [
   'type' => 'books',
   'variables' => [
      'color' => 'red',
      'size' => 'large'
   ]
]
```

I want my url to like this:

```
http://example.com/?type=books&variables={"color":"red","size":"large"}
```

encoded above url:

```
http://example.com/?type=books&variables=%7B%22color%22%3A%22red%22%2C%22size%22%3A%22large%22%7D
```

But when I use:

```
Http::get('http://example.com', $params);
```

The API server returns error.

But when I use:

```
Http::get('http://example.com/?type=books&variables={"color":"red","size":"large"}');
```

It works well.

So how can I convert my params array into url ?

(I don't have access to API server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `json_encode()`

```php
 $params = [
            'type' => 'books',
            'variables' => json_encode([
               'color' => 'red',
               'size' => 'large'
            ])
         ]

$url = "http://example.com?".http_build_query($params);

Http::get($url);
```

and `http_build_query()`
ref link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php